# sqoop import is not moving entire table in hdfs

Tags: sqoop

I had create a small database with few tables in mysql. Now I transferring the table using sqoop to HDFS.
Below is the sqoop command:
*sqoop import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqooptest  --username root -P  --table emp  --m 1 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver* 

**I am not getting last 2 columns, salary and dept**
Output of the above command
*1201gopalmanager*
*1202manishaProof reader*
*1203khalilphp dev*
*1204prasanthphp dev*
*1205kranthiadmin*

MySql table is :
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+
| id   | name     | deg          | salary | dept |
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1201 | gopal    | manager      |  50000 | TP   |
| 1202 | manisha  | Proof reader |  50000 | TP   |
| 1203 | khalil   | php dev      |  30000 | AC   |
| 1204 | prasanth | php dev      |  30000 | AC   |
| 1205 | kranthi  | admin        |  20000 | TP   |
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+

I tried with using "**--fields-terminated-by , **", or "**--input-fields-terminated-by ,**" but failed

Also when I am using mapper count like (--m 3), getting only single file in HDFS.

I am using apache Sqoop on ubuntu machince.

Thanks in advance for finding solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems correct. Providing some steps below that you can try to follow once again and see if it works:

1) Create the table and populate it (MySQL)

```
mysql> create database sqooptest;
mysql> use sqooptest;
mysql> create table emp (id int, name varchar(100), deg varchar(50), salary int, dept varchar(10));

mysql> insert into emp values(1201, 'gopal','manager',50000,'TP');
mysql> insert into emp values(1202, 'manisha','Proof reader',50000,'TP');
mysql> insert into emp values(1203, 'khalil','php dev',30000,'AC');
mysql> insert into emp values(1204, 'prasanth','php dev',30000,'AC');
mysql> insert into emp values(1205, 'kranthi','admin',20000,'TP');

mysql> select * from emp;
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+
| id   | name     | deg          | salary | dept |
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+
| 1201 | gopal    | manager      |  50000 | TP   |
| 1202 | manisha  | Proof reader |  50000 | TP   |
| 1203 | khalil   | php dev      |  30000 | AC   |
| 1204 | prasanth | php dev      |  30000 | AC   |
| 1205 | kranthi  | admin        |  20000 | TP   |
+------+----------+--------------+--------+------+
```

2) Run the import

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqooptest --username root -P --table emp --m 1 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --target-dir /tmp/sqoopout
```

3) Check result

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /tmp/sqoopout/*
1201,gopal,manager,50000,TP
1202,manisha,Proof reader,50000,TP
1203,khalil,php dev,30000,AC
1204,prasanth,php dev,30000,AC
1205,kranthi,admin,20000,TP
```

`HDFS` has only one file (`part-m-00000`):

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /tmp/sqoopout
Found 2 items
/tmp/sqoopout/_SUCCESS
/tmp/sqoopout/part-m-00000
```

This is because the data size is small, and one mapper is sufficient to process it. You can verify this by looking at the sqoop logs, which outputs:

```
Job Counters
        Launched map tasks=1
```